# How to detach from stream?

Tags: perforce, p4v

I'm using Perforce 2015.2. I attached my workspace to a Perforce stream with a command similar to:

```
p4 client -s -S //Product/Main
```

Now I'd like to detach the workspace from the stream. I tried:

```
p4 client -s -S //
```

But got an error:

> Stream '//' is not the correct format of '//depotname/string'

How can I detach from my workspace from the stream?

Answer (score 1):

By "detach my workspace from the stream", I assume you mean that you want your workspace to stop referring to the stream's files, and instead you want to refer to some set of files in a non-stream depot.

So:

1. `p4 client` to bring up your client spec in your editor
2. Delete the line that reads: `Stream:  //Product/Main`
3. Change the lines below `View:` that look like:

   //Product/Main/... //my-client/...

to instead read:

```
//depot/some/path/... //my-client/some/path/...
```

4. Save and close out of your editor.